# Redirect links of a php application

Tags: apache-httpd, php, webserver, domain, links

This is with Apache 2.4 webserver.

I copied the hole site from one domain to another. Let us say from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com/subdir/`. The site is a webservice with news and advertisements.

The site has the php application that is adverisement server. This application has many links to `olddomain.com` in the code, in config files etc. So links are to the old domain. These links are literal, not any relative.

May I do anything to redirect all those link to the newdomain? I was thinking about something like .htaccess with redirection but in fact I have no idea to which folder place such a .htaccess.

How to redirect links?

Comment: use `regex` (if you dare) to replace links. Or better, write another php script that loads html file using `file_get_contents` then uses `xpath` to replace links

Comment: The proper way to fix this issue is to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you own the old domain, this looks like a job for the `mod_alias` Apache module, and here's a [guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/redirect-urls-with-the-apache-web-server/).

Here is some documentation on the [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) & [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directives it provides.

Or, if you're trying to do something fancy there's also the [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) module.